# Mistake in parameterization of a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular and compact surface. Let

- $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ a function with $f(p)=\|p\|^2$ for every $p \in S$ and
- $X(u,v)$ be a parametrization of $S$.

My textbook says that the function $g=f \circ X(u,v)$ is:
$$g = \langle \, X(u,v)-X(u_0,v_0), N\circ X(u,v)\,\rangle $$
Where $N$ is the Gauss map.

I can't find how can $g$ be expressed this way, besides,
$$ g = f \circ X = \| X(u,v)\|^2=\langle \, X(u,v),X(u,v) \, \rangle $$
Maybe the textbook has a mistake?

Comment: There's some definite miscommunication going on. The formula given has nothing to do with $f\circ X$. For starters, where did $(u_0,v_0)$ come from? I think you should read the whole section very carefully and see what they're actually doing.